# Using "tar" command in Terminal for multiple folders/files

Tags: macos, terminal, tar

I have many files like these

```
SomeDirectory/RandomName.spa
SomeDirectory/AnotherRandomName.spa
SomeDirectory/YetAnotherRandomName.spa
```

...

I want to unpack every `.spa` file in `SomeDirectory` to their each seperate folders, with the same name. I would use something like - `tar -xvf`, but with what attributes?

Afterwards I want to pack every folder in `SomeDirectory` again back to `RandomName.spa`, (keeping the name of folder). The command would be `tar -cvf`, but with what attributes?

Comment: Have you read the man page for `tar`? If not, then I'd suggest doing so.  In a Terminal type `tar` and then control-click it selecting "Open man Page".   Then if you're still confused, edit your question and try describing in better detail.

Comment: I assume that the `*.spa` files are actually tar archives? What happens if you run `tar -xvf RandomName.spa`?

Comment: @user3439894 - ok, I'll take a look at it

Comment: @patrix - yes they are. It would unpack the specified archive in folder. However I want to unpack all of the archives, instead of doing manually for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that (1) the `.spa` files are actually `.tar` archives, (2) you are in `SomeDirectory`, and (3) that directories with the names of the archives you want to extract do not exist, the following piece of code should achieve what you want:

```
for a in *.spa
  do a_dir=`expr $a : '\(.*\).spa'`
  mkdir $a_dir
  tar -xvf $a -C $a_dir;
done
```

Or in case you prefer a one-liner:

```
for a in *.spa; do a_dir=`expr $a : '\(.*\).spa'`; mkdir $a_dir; tar -xvf $a -C $a_dir; done
```

The first line in the `for` loop strips the `.spa` from the archive name and assigns it to a variable, which is used in the second line to make a directory with that name, and in the third line in `tar` with the `-C` argument.

The `-C` argument in `tar` only changes directory during extraction and doesn't actually *make* one, making things a a bit more complicated than they should be.

Credit: This answer is a slight modification of https://superuser.com/a/748567/226246